Math font labels in TKZ figure
I have a few labels in the TKZ figure that I want to use math fonts such as $\mathcal{Q}$. How to do that? Thanks!
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}\begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} \tkzDefPoints{2.7/1.5/Q,0.5/2/Q_1} \tkzLabelPoints[thick](Q,Q_1) \end{tikzpicture}\end{document}


\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{2.7/1.5/Q,0.5/2/Q_1}
\tkzLabelPoints(Q_1)
\tkzLabelPoint(Q){$\mathcal{Q}$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you very much!
